# Django urls uuid not working

Tags: django, django-urls

In the following, if the url is set as ,what should be the pattern for uuid?

urls.py

```
url(r'^getbyempid/(?P<emp_id>[0-9]+)/(?P<factory_id>[0-9]+)$',views.empdetails)
```

Doesnt work,

```
http://10.0.3.79:8000/app1/getbyempid/1/b9caf199-26c2-4027-b39f-5d0693421506
```

but this works

```
http://10.0.3.79:8000/app1/getbyempid/1/2
```

Answer (score 53, accepted):

As well as the digits 0-9, the uuid can also include digits a-f and hyphens, so you could should change the pattern to

```
(?P<factory_id>[0-9a-f-]+)
```

You could have a more strict regex, but it's not usually worth it. In your view you can do something like:

```
try:
    factory = get_object_or_404(Factory, id=factory_id)
except ValueError:
    raise Http404
```

which will handle invalid uuids or uuids that do not exist in the database.

Comment: You might want to add a `try ... except ValueError: raise Http404()` in order to treat input that is not convertible to a uuid the same as invalid uuids.

Comment: @moooeeeep good point - if you are using the `UUIDField` then catching `ValueError` is required for strings which are not convertible to a uuid.

Comment: I think `UUIDField` throws a `ValidationError` if the uuid is malformed; just to be a bit more specific.

Answer (score 77):

Since Django 2.0 you don't even need to worry about regex for *UUID* and *int* with new Django feature: [Path Converters](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#path-converters).

**Make code elegant again**:

```
from django.urls import path
...

urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('getbyempid/<int:emp_id>/<uuid:factory_id>', views.empdetails)
]
```

Comment: Didn't work for me with `re_path(r'^(?P<Model>[A-Za-z]+)/<uuid:id>)',`

Comment: @Charlestone i believe _path converters_ do not work in `re_path`.

Comment: @vishes_shell They do, but you need to make some changes: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/urls/

Comment: I used it with re_path but it didnt work. Instead, `(?P<factory_id>[0-9a-f-]+)` fixed my bug.

Answer (score 6):

Just to complete other answers, please note that the Regex should be `a-f` not `a-z`, so:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^request/(?P<form_id>[0-9A-Fa-f-]+)', views.request_proxy)
]
```

something like above could be the most accurate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your url patterns is taking only numbers, try this one:

```
url(r'^getbyempid/(?P<emp_id>[0-9a-z-]+)/(?P<factory_id>[0-9a-z-]+)$',views.empdetails)
```

Answer (score 0):

had the same problem,
fixed it with this :

```py
url(r'^offer_details/(?P<uuid>[0-9a-f\-]{32,})$', offer_details, name='offer_details')
`
```